# Error can not break inheritance

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

I was wondering if anyone could help or point me in the right direction. I'm getting the following error when trying to break inheritance on items in SharePoint Online.
You cannot break inheritance for this item because there are too many items with unique permissions in this list

Is there anywhere that documents this for SharePoint Online?

Comment: how many items in the list?

Comment: Over 300 thousand items.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits), the maximum number of items in a list with unique permissions is 5,000:

> Unique security scopes per list or library - 5,000. For large lists, design to have as few unique permissions as possible.

Can you split your list out into smaller lists, or reduce the number of items in the list with unique permissions?  Would your application allow you to keep a 'Live' list and a larger 'Archive' list with broader permissions for example?

Comment: Thanks for the post, unfortunately we can't really split it, I guess we could  roll the permissions up to the route or its parent. But I guess that could still cause problems

Comment: Do you allow folders in your list?  Can you apply the permissions at a folder level and let list items inherit from their parent folder to reduce the number of unique permissions? (I know that using folders in lists isn't always the best plan and can have unintended drawbacks, but it may help you here, as it would be the folders that had the permissions set, not the individual items).

Comment: We allow folders, so yeah I guess we could scrap adding unique permissions to folders and roll it up

Comment: If you have folders, you can split the content to the more libraries based on folders structure, so if you need unique permissions, do that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with splitting the content to more libraries. If you want to do it automatically or if, by any chance, the 300 thousand items are coming from your CRM, a good solution would be the third-party add-on SharePoint Structure Creator.

Comment: Have a look at my blog article on this [Solutions and workarounds for SharePoint permission limits](https://www.connecting-software.com/blog/solutions-and-workarounds-for-sharepoint-permission-limits/)